# Markdown include section from another file

Tags: markdown, docfx

I want to include just a section from another markdown file in our documentation base.

Our documentation is built in DocFx.

I'm able to include the whole file but I just want a section from the file.
For example, this works
`[!include[title](file2.md)]`

But it doesn't allow me to embed just a section if I use this
`[!include[title](file2.md#header2)]`

My guess is it isn't supported but wanted to reach out in case someone knew something I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

To include a specific section of a markdown file, I would use the `xref` cross-referencing syntax which supports the use of hashtag. See DocFX documentation [here](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/links_and_cross_references.html#using-hashtag-in-cross-reference) for an example.